# VueJs route to / or home

Tags: vue.js, routes

I have a problem with my routing.

When i do my build, 
And when i go on my ****/dist/, my routing on home do not work.

But the page is blank with only the navbar.

I would like to go on the Login page.

Thank you for your futur help :)

this is my App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" >
    <!-- class="container"-->
    <b-container fluid>
      <navbar></navbar>
      <router-view/>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Navbar from './components/navbar/Navbar'
export default {
  name: 'App',
    methods: {
    },
    components: {
        Navbar
    }
}
</script>
<style>

</style>
```

And this is my router

```
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Login,
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login,
        meta: { 
            guest: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'userboard',
        component: UserBoard,
        meta: { 
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/myBooked',
        name: 'Booked',
        component: Booked,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/admin',
        name: 'admin',
        component: Admin,
        meta: { 
            requiresAuth: true,
            is_admin : true
        }
    },
```

EDIT 2019-101-18 : @Sajib Khan

In main.js (default) with :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Router :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Booked from '@/components/Booked'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import UserBoard from '@/components/UserBoard'
import Admin from '@/components/Admin'

Vue.use(Router)

let router = new Router({
    //base: '/dist',
    mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Login,
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login,
        meta: { 
            guest: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'userboard',
        component: UserBoard,
        meta: { 
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/myBooked',
        name: 'Booked',
        component: Booked,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/admin',
        name: 'admin',
        component: Admin,
        meta: { 
            requiresAuth: true,
            is_admin : true
        }
    },
  ]
})
```

Comment: Where have you initialized Vue instance (`new Vue` {...}).. can you share the code?

Comment: The router is in folder router->index.js 
And New Vue -> In main.js (default) with : (I also edited my mainpost)

`new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})`

Comment: Do you see any error in console? it will be great help if you share a working code-pen/jsFiddle example.

Comment: My code is note secure for the moment...
But i don't see any error.
Juste, when I am on the home page, I just see the navbar but not the Login page..

Comment: BUT, i use the "Dist" folder with "npm run build" and put it on the www of WAMP server. When i use :
npm run dev, its works. But not with the WAMP server.